# Perform UNION ALL regardless of column order in the two joined tables

Tags: sql-server, union

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE1 
FROM Table2
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM Table3;
GO
```

I am using this query to stack two tables together into one table. These tables should have the columns in the exact same order for this query to execute successfully.

I am wondering if there is a trick we can do so that it works regardless of the column order. Is there a way to instruct SQL Server to automatically line up the columns from both tables by name and perform the `UNION`?

In SAS, the trick is to write a `OUTER UNION CORR` query, for example.

Comment: You should never use select * anyway. It is a SQl antipattern and causes the server to be inefficient. In a union, adding one column to one of the tables will break the query.

Comment: Yeah, specify the column list explicitly. Never use `*`.

Comment: @HLGEM: "never use `select *`" -- You've more recently said it was OK for "quick ad hoc query". In the interest of fairness, [here's my (current) position on the matter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9328000/15354)

Answer (score 4):

I think you have two options. Either type out the columns in your query or do something with dynamic SQL.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @col nvarchar(max)

select @col = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.COLUMN_NAME)
                     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as C
                     where C.TABLE_NAME = 'Table2'
                     order by C.ORDINAL_POSITION
                     for xml path(''), type).value('.',  'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

set @sql = 'select '+@col+' into Table1 from Table2 union all '+
           'select '+@col+' from Table3'

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

In standard SQL (removing the `INTO` clause):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2
UNION ALL CORRESPONDING
SELECT * FROM Table3
```

Sadly, SQL Server has not yet implemented `CORRESPONDING` qualifier (same applies to `INTERSECT CORRESPONDING` and `EXCEPT CORRESPONDING`).

---

Fully utilising standard SQL (and dropping what I trust is redundant `ALL`), simply:

```
TABLE Table2 UNION CORRESPONDING TABLE Table3
```

Comment: actually SQl Server 2008 has Except and Intersect

Comment: @HLGEM: I meant that SQL Server has not implemented  `INTERSECT CORRSPONDING` and `EXCEPT CORRESPONDING`. I've edited to hopefully make this clearer.

Comment: For those wondering, wtf, https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/212266/2639

Comment: I would also suggest not using the version of `CORRESPONDING` wo/ column names, as it carries with it all the detriments of a `NATURAL` join. Instead, if SQL-Server had the proper feature set you could do TABLE table2 UNION ALL CORRESPONDING BY (col1,col2) bar;

Comment: @EvanCarroll Good point about `TABLE`, I've updated my answer. However, I don't agree your point about 'detriments' of `NATURAL JOIN`.

Comment: Just consider what would happen if you had two rows with the same name, like `ts_modified`, or `ts_in`, `name, or `description`

Comment: Because (a) that's not always possible, and (b) it's absurd. Think about about a pivot from with an EAV, or a self-join. `SELECT foo.*, eav1.value AS foo, eav2.value AS bar FROM foo JOIN eav AS eav1 USING (foo_id) JOIN eav2 AS eav2 USING (foo_id) WHERE eav1.name = 'foo' AND eav2.name = 'bar';` And not to mention there is no mechanism to ensure data-names are globally unique so if integrity is tied to a constant that the database isn't enforcing, you're doing something wrong. You're better to be explicit and not assume it.

Comment: I'm just stating that if you don't specify the columns in the join conditions you're using a half baked idiom that requires you to know all of the columns in all of your tables at all times, and provides no database guarantees as to whether they're unique. That sounds like a bad idea to save a few key strokes to me, which is why no one does it (that I'm aware of). And why `NATURAL JOINS` are probably the worst idea in the spec.

Comment: When you added `name` to your customer table instead of `customer_name`, were you guilty of saving a few key strokes? :) Seriously, if there is a good reason for creating duplicate names in the same schema, I haven't heard it so please let me know. Bottom line: if you design a schema with unique data element names and defend yourself against breaking changes then `NATURAL JOIN`, `UNION CORRESPONDING`, etc will work just fine; if you don't then they won't. No argument here.